# Google Map API Implementation with variable calling

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

This is my Google map code below:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
InitMap("[['Leslie Fleming',41.977, -71.3248, 1 ],['Chris Reale',41.977, -71.3248, 2 ],['Michael Anello',41.977, -71.3248, 3 ],['Ed Pariseau Jr',41.977, -71.3248, 4 ],['Ryan Higgens',41.977, -71.3248, 5 ]]", "41.977, -71.3248");
function InitMap(MapElement, MapPointer){
    var locations = MapElement;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(MapPointer),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
}
</script>
```

Why it is not working? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: What is "not working"? Did you use a debugger to find a reason?

Comment: if I use hard code then it works

Comment: Please don't down vote. If any one find out the error then tell me otherwise leave it

Comment: Don't need to hire a programmer. I have the potential to solve this.

Comment: if you have the potential why post it here in the first place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the code I have solve it. This is multiple marker Google map. You can use it through AJAX. I don't need to hire a programmer. I can able to solve it.

```
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
InitMap([["Leslie Fleming",41.977, -71.3248, 1 ],["Chris Reale",41.977, -71.3248, 2 ],["Michael Anello",41.977, -71.3248, 3 ],["Ed Pariseau Jr",41.977, -71.3248, 4 ],["Ryan Higgens",41.977, -71.3248, 5 ]], 41.977, -71.3248);
function InitMap(MapElement, latitude, longitude){
    var locations = MapElement;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

See the code I have solve it. This is multiple marker Google map. You can use it through AJAX. I don't need to hire a programmer. I can able to solve it.

```
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
InitMap([["Leslie Fleming",41.977, -71.3248, 1 ],["Chris Reale",41.977, -71.3248, 2 ],["Michael Anello",41.977, -71.3248, 3 ],["Ed Pariseau Jr",41.977, -71.3248, 4 ],["Ryan Higgens",41.977, -71.3248, 5 ]], 41.977, -71.3248);
function InitMap(MapElement, latitude, longitude){
    var locations = MapElement;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: So all you *really* needed to do was make the first element an array by leaving out the quote marks (which make it into a string). Then you wouldn't have to `eval` a string to get the array you want. In your original code, call the function with `InitMap([['Leslie Fleming',41.977, -71.3248, 1 ],[...]...],...)` so your first argument is an array of arrays, not a string. -1 for using `eval`.

Comment: Exactly. I expected this type of answer. Thanks, your thought and my code both are working :)